# Patch Gecko to introduce a synonym for a supported CSS property ("appearance" for "-moz-appearance")

Tags: gecko

I am working on a firefox fork and would like to duplicate -moz-apperance as appearance. I have tried duplicating it as a shorthand property but this throws errors at the compile stage using     ./mach build The documentation seems cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

There's [documentation about implementing new CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Adding_a_new_style_property), which might be hard to follow, but browsers are complex pieces of software.

(Currently this question is too broad to provide an answer that's not link-only.)

**update:** an actual answer from dbaron (via mozilla.dev.platform):

> by adding entries to:
>   https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/nsCSSPropAliasList.h

Comment: Sorry but I red this on the mailing list when I asked it(I am adam@imgland,xyz)

Comment: @TheFarmingBunny I guessed so, but this page may also be found by other people with a similar question, that's why I added it. Glad you found the solution, by the way!